# Making `subset()` work in a function

Tags: r

The goal is to be able to use a "subset expression" (not a logical vector) as an (optional) argument to a user-defined function and use that to compute the subset of a data-frame.

```
x <- data.frame(a=1, b=gl(2,5))

f <- function(data, subset) {
    if (!missing(subset))
        data <- subset(data, subset)
    data
}
```

The code above doesn't work, and neither does

```
f <- function(data, subset) {
    if (!missing(subset))
        data <- data[with(data, subset), ]
    data
}
```

In both cases I get an error when `subset` is supplied.

```
> f(x, b == 2)
Error in f(x, b == 2) (from frame.r!322341dM#2) : object 'b' not found
```

Desired output:

```
> f(x)
   a b
1  1 1
2  1 1
3  1 1
4  1 1
5  1 1
6  1 2
7  1 2
8  1 2
9  1 2
10 1 2
> f(x, b == 2)
   a b
6  1 2
7  1 2
8  1 2
9  1 2
10 1 2
```

Comment: You need   `x$b == 2`.

Comment: b is not a variable, it is a column in x, so you need it to enter the function (or be pasted in the function) in a way that R understands.  It could be as G5W says or you could set up the function to take three attributes, the data frame, the column name and the value and then paste them together in the function to extract your desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one seems work. You have to tell `f` that second arg is an expression:

```
f <- function(data, ss) {
    if (!missing(ss)){
        e <- substitute(ss)
        r <- eval(e, data, parent.frame())
        data <- subset(data, r)
    }
    data
}

# > f(x, b == 2)
#    a b
# 6  1 2
# 7  1 2
# 8  1 2
# 9  1 2
# 10 1 2
```

replace argument name `ss` with `subset` won't work. I am not sure why. Actually, I came up with by navigating source code of `subset.data.frame`.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, edited. I saw this in source of `subset` but not sure what it does. Thanks for explaining this.

Answer (score 1):

Since your function basically has the same signature as `subset()`, you can also just pass along the parmeters directly to `subset()`.

```
f <- function(data, ss) {
    if (!missing(ss)){
        call <- unname(match.call())
        call[[1]] <- quote(subset)
        data <- eval(call, parent.frame())
    }
    data
}
```

The `unname()` is necessary here because you gave this function different parameter names than the `subset()` function. But basically we just swap the call to your function with a call to `subset()`. This means we don't have to do the "dirty work" of evaluating the filter in the proper context.